# React-Native Show an image illustration when there is no network (No internet connection status)

Tags: image, react-native, internet-connection

I am (newbie) working on an iOS app using react-native. I want to show an image illustration when app goes offline or there is no internet connection to inform the user. I have done all set up required such as :- 
1. My image is at src/assets folder
2. using this image in screen - which will be displayed when app detects no internet connection.

In iOS simulator it works fine, but when I run it on iPhone it does not show that image only text appears.

NoInternetScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Image, Text} from 'react-native';

const NoInternetScreen = props => {

    return(
        <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../assets/NoConnection.png')}/>
            <View style={styles.textContainer}>
             <Text style={styles.text}>No Internet connection</Text>
            </View>

        </View>
    )

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    imageContainer: {
        flex:1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginHorizontal: 20,
    },
    image: {
        width: 160,
        height: 220,
        alignSelf: 'center',
    },
    textContainer: {
        marginVertical: 15,

    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 20,
    }

});

export default NoInternetScreen;
```

Login.js - which uses NoInternetScreen

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
import {NetworkContext} from '../NetworkContext';
import NoInternetScreen from './NoInternetScreen';

const Login =  props => {

  const isConnected = useContext(NetworkContext);

  return (
    isConnected ? <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text> Login </Text>
    </View> : <NoInternetScreen/>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  }
});

export default Login;
```

Could you please suggest what could be done to fix it?

Thanks and Regards,
Ankur

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: added the example I am using.